Android Studio: No files were found with the provided path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk. No artifacts will be uploaded
I'm learning to setting up CI/CD with GitHub Actions for my android app. I am following this tutorial. But I am getting a warning:

No files were found with the provided path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk. No artifacts will be uploaded.

Here is my failed apk generation github action screenshot:

Here is my workflow:
name: AndroidBuild

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.0

      - name: Setup Java JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3.13.0
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Upload a Build Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.3
        with:
          name: Mealz.apk
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk


Missing ./gradlew build step.
